# Python for loop flow when calling a time consuming function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, for-loop

I have implemented the following code:

```
lines=[]
    with open('path_to_file', 'r+') as source:
        for line in source:
            line = line.replace('\n','').strip()
            if line.split()[-1] != 'sent':
                # do some operation on line without 'sent' tag
                upload(data1.zip)
                upload(data2.zip) 
                do_operation(line)
                # tag the line
                line += '\tsent'
            line += '\n'
            # temporary save lines in a list
            lines.append(line)
        # move position to start of the file
        source.seek(0)
        # write back lines to the file
        source.writelines(lines)
```

I am calling upload methods in a section `#do some operation with lines without sent tag` to upload data to the cloud. As the data is a bit large (around 1GB), it takes a while to finish the upload. In the mean time, does the for loop go ahead to call `upload(data2)`? I am getting errors as I cannot upload simultaneously.

If yes, how can I avoid this?

EDIT:::

I have changed upload function to return status as done after uploading. So, how can I modify my main loop so that it will wait after calling `upload(data1.zip)` and then move on to `upload(data2.zip)`. I want to synchronize..

Comment: One of us is confused (yes, it might still be me).  You want to wait for the return value, but you don't want multiprocessing.  Doing things in parallel *is* multiprocessing.  Waiting for a result is synchronization -- which is the **join** function above.  Can you clarify your needs for us?

Comment: @Prune yes its me who is confused.. i want to synchronize..

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem might be that you don't want to try to upload more than one file at a time.

Your code doesn't try to do any parallel uploads. So I suspect that your `upload()` function is starting an upload process and then letting it run in the background while it returns to you.

If this is true, you can try some of these options:

1. Pass an option to the `upload` function that tells it to wait until the upload finishes before returning.
2. Discover (research) some attribute that you can use to synchronize your program with the process started by the `upload` function. For example, if the function returns the child process id, you could do a `wait` on that pid to complete. Or perhaps it writes the pid out to a pidfile - you could read in the number, and wait for it.
3. If you can't make the upload function do what you want synchronously, you might consider replacing calls to `upload()` with print statements to have your code generate some kind of script that could be executed separately, possibly with a different environment or using a different upload utility.

Comment: i have edited my upload function to return(status) after uploading is complete.. how can ask for loop to wait for the return value..sorry for basic question., new to python

Comment: If the upload function is waiting for the upload to complete, then you should be good to go. If you still have a problem with parallel uploads, can you edit your question to include the source of the `upload()` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can send them off as independent processes.  Use the Python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module; there are nice [tutorials](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html), too.

Your inner loop might look something like this:

```
up1 = Process(target=upload, args=(data1.zip,))
up2 = Process(target=upload, args=(data2.zip,))
up1.start()
up2.start()

# Now, do other stuff while these run
do_operation(line)
# tag the line
line += '\tsent'

# Wait for the uploads to finish -- in case they're slower than do_operation.
up1.join()
up2.join()
```

---

```
flag
```

> @Prune yes its me who is confused.. i want to synchronize.

Excellent; we have *that* cleared up.  The things you synchronize are separate processes.  You have your main process waiting for the result of your child process, the **upload**.  Multiple processes is called ... :-)

Are we at a solution point now?  I *think* the pieces you need are in one (or at most two) of these answers.

Comment: edited my question a bit .. how can i do it without miltiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiprocessing` do the time consuming work.

```
import multiprocessing


# creates processes for your files, each file has its own processor
processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=upload, args=(zip_file,)) for zip_file in [data1.zip,data2.zip]]

# starts the processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# waits for all processes finish work
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# It will not go here until all files finish uploading.
...
...
```

Comment: i have edited my question. how can it be done without multiprocesing?